# Angular: consumindo API em kotlin nao consigo exibir retorno no template, somente no console... erro [ object Object]

Tags: array, angular, api, objetos

Olá, na minha frontend angular com requisicao da minha API kotlin+postgreSQL nao estou recebendo os valores no template, apenas no console:

```
{content: Array(3), pageable: {…}, last: true, totalPages: 1, totalElements: 3, …}
   content:(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]                       
   empty: false
   first: true
   last: true
   number: 0
   numberOfElements: 3
   pageable:{sort: {…}, offset: 0, pageSize: 20, pageNumber: 0, paged: true, …}
   size: 20
   sort: {empty: false, unsorted: false, sorted: true}
   totalElements: 3
   totalPages: 1
   [[Prototype]]: Object
```

e o error:

> Error: NG02200: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object
> Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables,
> such as Arrays. Did you mean to use the keyvalue pipe?

Direto na API ela retorna assim:

```
    {
  "content": [
    {
      "id": 48,
      "titulo": "dsadas",
      "descricao": "dsadsdas",
      "status": "SOLICITADA",
      "dataSolicitacao": "2022-09-29T17:50:18.497686"
    },
    {
      "id": 47,
      "titulo": "TESTE MINERACAO2",
      "descricao": " TESTETE",
      "status": "SOLICITADA",
      "dataSolicitacao": "2022-09-29T17:38:45.07944"
    },
    {
      "id": 46,
      "titulo": "MINERACAONOVA",
      "descricao": "TESTEMINERACAO",
      "status": "SOLICITADA",
      "dataSolicitacao": "2022-09-29T17:38:23.240623"
    }
  ],
  "pageable": {
    "sort": {
      "empty": false,
      "unsorted": false,
      "sorted": true
    },
    "offset": 0,
    "pageSize": 20,
    "pageNumber": 0,
    "paged": true,
    "unpaged": false
  },
  "last": true,
  "totalPages": 1,
  "totalElements": 3,
  "size": 20,
  "number": 0,
  "sort": {
    "empty": false,
    "unsorted": false,
    "sorted": true
  },
  "first": true,
  "numberOfElements": 3,
  "empty": false
}
```

Meu html:

```
<tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let ext of extracoes " class="line">
        <td class=itens-container>  {{ext.id}} </td>
        <td class=itens-container> {{ext.titulo}} </td>
        <td class=itens-container> {{ext.descricao}} </td>
        <td class=itens-container> {{ext.status}} </td>

        <td>
          <a href="#" [routerLink]="['/extracao/',ext.id,'view']" class="btn"> Visualizar </a>
          <a href="#" [routerLink]="['/extracao/',ext.id,'edit']" class="btn"> Editar </a>
          <button class="btn-delete"(click)=deleteExtracao(ext.id)>Deletar</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

Meu component:

```
export class ExtracaoComponent implements OnInit {
  extracoes!: Extracao[]; 

  constructor(public extracaoService: ExtracaoService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getExtracoes();
  }

  getExtracoes(){
  this.extracaoService.getAll().subscribe(data=>{
      this.extracoes = data;
      console.log(this.extracoes);
    })
  }
```

Na parte Service:

```
getAll(): Observable<Extracao[]>{
    return this.http.get<Extracao[]>(api_path)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.errorHandler)
    )
  }
```

Estou usando tambem um interface model:

```
export interface Extracao {
  id: number;
  titulo: string;
  descricao: string;
  status: string;
  dataSolicitacao: Date;
  dataEdicao: Date;
  idMinerio: number;
  idArea: number;
}
```

Comment: provavelmente você não está deserializando ou pegando o retorno correto da resposta da sua api na sua chamada do angular

Comment: Se eu dou um retorno como exemplo {{extracoes | json}} ele me retorna um texto em json no template...

Comment: dentro do método `getExtracoes` no seu componente,  pelo retorno da sua api tenta mudar para `data.content` ao invés de apenas `data`

Comment: Retorna que nao reconhece a propriedade .content

Comment: lá no seu service dentro método `getAll()` usa o `map` dentro do `pipe` para apenas mapear as propriedades da interface  `Extracao`. Algo como `pipe(map(response => response.content as Extracao)) `